# How to add values in arraylist of arraylist?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am retrieving longitude and latitude values of each user from firebase but problem is that i want to add that values of each user in one list so there are many list that's why I'm using arraylist of arraylist.

So for first user

> longitude = 12345 , latitude = 23456

and for 2nd user

> longitude = 45678 , latitude = 67891.

Now my question is i want to add longi and lat of first user in list [ 12345 , 23456 ] and for 2nd user [ 45678 , 67891]
By using arraylist of arraylist is equal to [[
12345,23456 ],[ 45678 , 67891 ] ].

My code:-

Initialization:-

```
    ArrayList<String> longitudes = new ArrayList<>();//for storing latitude and longitude values
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String> > aList =
            new ArrayList<ArrayList<String> >();
//for storing combine values of longitude and latitude
```

```
                databaseReference.child("hospital").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                        longitudes.clear();
                      
                         for (DataSnapshot snapshot1: snapshot.getChildren()) {
                             longitudes.add(snapshot1.child("longitude").getValue().toString());
                             longitudes.add(snapshot1.child("latitude").getValue().toString());
                             aList.add(count,longitudes);                           
                             count++;
                         }

                        
                        count=0;
                        }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                    }
                });
```

But it is giving output as

> [[12345,23456,45678 , 67891],[ 12345,23456,45678 , 67891]]
> It is repeating the values

But I am expecting for each user like

> [[12345,23456],[45678 , 67891]]

Comment: your `longitudes` is always the same list. Create a new `ArrayList` and assign it to `longitudes` on every loop iteration instead of clearing and reusing the existing one.

Comment: exactly where I need to create and add the values

Comment: There's a typo/logic error/naming issue in the code; you're adding both longitude *and* latitude to the longitudes array. `longitudes.add(snapshot1.child("longitude")` and then the error `longitudes.add(snapshot1.child("latitude")`. You could/should have a separate array for each, or, why not just create an object to hold both lon and lat and then add that object to an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `longitudes` is always the same list. Create a new `ArrayList` and assign it to `longitudes` on every loop iteration instead of clearing and reusing the existing one.

Remove your existing `longitudes` variable and make your loop look like this:

```
ArrayList<String> longitudes;
for (DataSnapshot snapshot1: snapshot.getChildren()) {
    longitudes = new ArrayList<>()
    longitudes.add(snapshot1.child("longitude").getValue().toString());
    longitudes.add(snapshot1.child("latitude").getValue().toString());
    aList.add(count,longitudes);                           
    count++;
}
```

I would further like to suggest not to represent lat+long as a List with 2 elements, just create your own class with 2 fields orif your are on java14+, use a record:

```
public record LatLong (String lat, String long) {}
```

and then use that in your list:

```
ArrayList<LatLong > aList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: great .. it works . but in my code also i am clearing the list. then why it stores that previous values

Comment: You clear it only *once* before the loop. Then you run through the loop twice adding the values to the same shared list (and add that list to the outer list twice).

Answer (score -1):

The implementation is basically wrong as I can see you are trying to add in the longitudes array for the latitude as well.

```
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    longitudes.clear();
    
    for (DataSnapshot snapshot1: snapshot.getChildren()) {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap();
            map.put('longitude',snapshot1.child("longitude").getValue().toString());
            map.put('latitude',snapshot1.child("latitude").getValue().toString());
            aList.add(count,map);                           
            count++;
        }
        count=0;
    }
```

Comment: OP tries to represent lat and long using a List with 2 entries. A Map is not really a good replacement here. Also your code doesnt compile because String literals s in java use double quotes.

Comment: i tried with this code. its working but it is giving longi and lat as string with values

Comment: you can make the map generics as Double or Integer as per your requirement and can store the data type.
Like,
Map<String, Double> map = new HashMap();